# Slate - TypeScript - return the required info out of a promise

Tags: typescript, palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

my code

```
@Function()
@Edits(XYZ)
public async fctLargestNumber(): Promise<XYZ[]> {
    const maxObject = Objects.search()
            .xYZ()
            // .groupBy(e => e.lngPlanningNumber.topValues())
            // .segmentBy(e => e.lngPlanningNumber.topValues())
            // .filter(data_column => data_column.lngPlanningNumber.byIRanges({ min: 100000, max: 999999 }))
            .orderBy(data_column => data_column.lngPlanningNumber.desc())
            .takeAsync(1)
            //.valueOf();         
    return maxObject;
```

now i recieve an output like this:

```
[
{"typeId":"my-collection","primaryKey":{"id_pk":"ee1b1ac1-008b-479b-a748-01e8702927c9"}}
]
```

The question is now, how can i receive my result.

- How i can pick out the primary key value?
- How i can search for the requested result (integer) of column "lngPlanningNumber" which belongs to this id?
  The Promise makes me curious. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially Solved:

```
@Function()
@Edits(XYZ)
public fctGetLargestNumber(): Integer {
        let  DataResult = Objects
                .search()
                .xYZ()
                .orderBy(data_column => data_column.lngPlanningNumber.desc())
                .take(1)[0];
    const result = DataResult.lngPlanningNumber ?? 0
    return result;
}
```

Attention !!!!!
Changes to objects and links are propagated to the Objects.search() APIs **after** your function has finished executing. This means that Objects.search() APIs will use the old objects, properties and links. As a result, search, filtering, search arounds, and aggregations may not reflect the edits to the Ontology, including creation and deletion. **Your function will need to handle this case manually**.

--> so i have to create new question to this.....

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use the Platform tab and set up a simple **Object Set** that filters using the `id_pk` property and the value returned from your function.

Slate will resolve this into a list of objects (it will have length `1` in this case) as well as load all the properties in parallel arrays.

If you really want the "object" format (i.e. all the properties as keys of a single object) then grab the object RID from *that* response and use it in the **Object Context**, which takes an object RID and simply returns all the data for that object.